# Esperar Final Transición CSS con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy tratando de conseguir que cuando presiones los botones de borrado en un orden especifico, verifique que halla sido en el orden esperado, y en caso de que no sea así, se coloreen en rojo y espere unos 3 segundo (con la función syncDelay) antes de que la pagina ejecute la siguiente acción. El problema esta en la transiciones css, que se ejecuta el syncDelay antes de que termine la transición css del ultimo botón.

**Lo que espero es que la transición css se complete y después se ejecute el syncDelay**, pero de momento es al momento de darle click cuando lo ejecuta, he probado con varias opciones de stackoverflow como https://stackoverflow.com/a/53091494/17346126, [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://es.quish.tv/easily-wait-an-element-css-transition-using-native-vanilla-javascript) (sin mucho éxito porque no he conseguido instalarlo), [Detectar fin de una transición/animación CSS3 con Javascript](https://javifm.com/blog/detectar-fin-de-una-transici%C3%B3n/animaci%C3%B3n-css3-con-javascript/) , [transitionend Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_transitionend.asp) o el [promise.all](https://drafts.csswg.org/web-animations-1/#use-cases).

El codigo de parte de la parte de los botones, junto con su css y html.

```js
//Primer boton

let contador = 0; //Variable de contro
let array = [0, 0, 0]; //Array de control de los clicks.
const respuesta = [6, 5, 4];
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
let btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2')
let btn3 = document.getElementById('btn3')

function syncDelay(milliseconds) { //funcion de espera
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  var end = 0;
  while ((end - start) < milliseconds) {
    end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}
btn.onclick = function() {
  if (btn.classList.contains('active') || btn.classList.contains('activefail')) {

  } else {
    contador = contador + 1;
    btn.classList.toggle('active');
    i = array.indexOf(0);
    array = array.fill(3, i, i + 1);
    if (contador == 3) {
      if (JSON.stringify(array) == JSON.stringify(respuesta)) {
        console.log("si");
      } else {
        console.log("no");
        btn.classList.toggle('activefail');
        btn.classList.toggle('active');
        btn2.classList.toggle('activefail');
        btn2.classList.toggle('active');
        btn3.classList.toggle('activefail');
        btn3.classList.toggle('active');
        syncDelay(3000);
      }
    }
  }
}
//segundo  boton
btn2.onclick = function() {
  if (btn2.classList.contains('active') || btn2.classList.contains('activefail')) {

  } else {
    contador = contador + 1;
    btn2.classList.toggle('active');
    i = array.indexOf(0);
    array = array.fill(2, i, i + 1);
    if (contador == 3) {
      if (JSON.stringify(array) == JSON.stringify(respuesta)) {
        console.log("si");
      } else {
        console.log("no");
        btn.classList.toggle('activefail');
        btn.classList.toggle('active');
        btn2.classList.toggle('activefail');
        btn2.classList.toggle('active');
        btn3.classList.toggle('activefail');
        btn3.classList.toggle('active');
        syncDelay(3000);
      }
    }
  }
}
//tercer boton
btn3.onclick = function() {
  if (btn3.classList.contains('active') || btn3.classList.contains('activefail')) {

  } else {
    contador = contador + 1;
    btn3.classList.toggle('active');
    i = array.indexOf(0);
    array = array.fill(1, i, i + 1);
    if (contador == 3) {
      if (JSON.stringify(array) == JSON.stringify(respuesta)) {
        console.log("si");
      } else {
        console.log("no");
        btn.classList.toggle('activefail');
        btn.classList.toggle('active');
        btn2.classList.toggle('activefail');
        btn2.classList.toggle('active');
        btn3.classList.toggle('activefail');
        btn3.classList.toggle('active');
        syncDelay(3000);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Centrar elemento dentro de main */

.main {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1404px/*550px*/
  ;
  height: 658px/*315px*/
  ;
  line-height: 50px;
  /* Con «line-height» con el mismo valor numérico de la altura centras horizontalmente el texto */
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 7px;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/*Boton*/

.btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn.activefail {
  background: #f34121;
}

.btn.active {
  background: #2196f3;
}

.btn span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.btn:hover span {
  transform: scale(1.5) rotate(60deg) translateY(10px);
}

.btn.activefail span,
.btn.active span {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  border-left: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.btn span::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 12px -2px 0 #333, 12px -3px 0 #333 15px -1px 0 #333 6px -2px 0 #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn.activefail span::before,
.btn.activefail:hover span::before,
.btn.active:hover span::before,
.btn.active span::before {
  transform: scale(0);
}

.btn:hover span::before {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(50%) translateY(-10px);
}

.btn text {
  position: absolute;
  right: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn.activefail text,
.btn:hover text,
.btn.active text {
  transform: translateX(-50px) translateY(-5px) scale(0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Prueba</title>
</head>

<body>
  <container class="main">
    <a id="btn1" class="btn" style="position: absolute;/* width: 1vh; *//* flex-direction: row; */right: 5vw;/* left: auto; */ /* height: 100vh; *//* bottom: 0; */"><span></span><text>Delete</text></a>
    <a id="btn2" class="btn" style="position: absolute;/* width: 1vh; *//* flex-direction: row; */right: 33vw;/* left: auto; */ /* height: 100vh; *//* bottom: 0; */"><span></span><text>Delete</text></a>
    <a id="btn3" class="btn" style="position: absolute;/* width: 1vh; *//* flex-direction: row; */right: 61vw;/* left: auto; */ /* height: 100vh; *//* bottom: 0; */"><span></span><text>Delete</text></a>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tu problema es que `syncDelay` es un proceso bloqueante. Es un `while` que no permite hacer más nada y bloquea la página de cualquier cosa por 3 segundos. Por favor, no uses este tipo de código en tu programa. Usa `setTimeOut` en su lugar.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez si de verdad se trata de una transicion entonces existe el evento `transitionEnd` que escucha justamente eso, cuando una transicion ha terminado de ejecutarse, no es buena idea usar un `setTimeout` en este caso porque entonces siempre tendras que variar los tiempos manualmente o dejar un tiempo que quizas no sea el adecuado para otras transiciones mas cortas o largas.

Comment: @Riven transitionEnd no será escuchado si estás dentro de un ciclo bloqueante.

Comment: Si, no se ejecutaria, en este caso seria mejor no intentar manualmente bloquear la ejecucion mediante el ciclo que esta haciendo el `OP`, ya que como dices para eso esta el `setTimeout`, tambien esta el evento `transitionEnd`, para no tener que estar manejando el tiempo de cada transicion manualmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema no radica en que se ejecute el syncDelay antes del fin de la transición, el problema es que el syncDelay para la ejecución "sincrona" o lo que es lo mismo, para por completo la ejecución, de esta forma, aunque hayas cambiado las clases de los botones antes, cuando llega al syncDelay el navegador todavía no ha tenido tiempo de "pintar" las nuevas css para el botón y no lo hace hasta que no termina el delay. Para evitar esto debes utilizar setTimeout. En el código de ejemplo, simplemente he creado una función que elimina las clases y reinicia los contadores. Esta función se ejecuta cuando pasan 3 segundos después de haber cambiado las clases. Mientras, como los botones ya tienen la clase "activefail" si se hace click en cualquier botón, este no hace nada porque el evento click comprueba que no tenga esa clase antes de continuar. Cuando pasan los 3 segundos, todo vuelve a comenzar desde el principio. En el ejemplo que te adjunto, la respuesta correcta es click en centro, izquierda y derecha. Todo lo que no sea esa combinación, espera 3 segundos y vuelve a empezar.

```js
//Primer boton

let contador = 0; //Variable de contro
let array = [0, 0, 0]; //Array de control de los clicks.
const respuesta = [2, 1, 3];
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
let btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2')
let btn3 = document.getElementById('btn3')

function syncDelay(milliseconds) { //funcion de espera
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  var end = 0;
  while ((end - start) < milliseconds) {
    end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}
btn.onclick = function() {
  if (btn.classList.contains('active') || btn.classList.contains('activefail')) {

  } else {
    contador = contador + 1;
    btn.classList.toggle('active');
    i = array.indexOf(0);
    array = array.fill(3, i, i + 1);
    if (contador == 3) {
      if (JSON.stringify(array) == JSON.stringify(respuesta)) {
        console.log("si");
      } else {
        console.log("no");
        btn.classList.toggle('activefail');
        btn.classList.toggle('active');
        btn2.classList.toggle('activefail');
        btn2.classList.toggle('active');
        btn3.classList.toggle('activefail');
        btn3.classList.toggle('active');
        setTimeout(activabotones, 3000);
      }
    }
  }
}
//segundo  boton
btn2.onclick = function() {
  if (btn2.classList.contains('active') || btn2.classList.contains('activefail')) {

  } else {
    contador = contador + 1;
    btn2.classList.toggle('active');
    i = array.indexOf(0);
    array = array.fill(2, i, i + 1);
    if (contador == 3) {
      if (JSON.stringify(array) == JSON.stringify(respuesta)) {
        console.log("si");
      } else {
        console.log("no");
        btn.classList.toggle('activefail');
        btn.classList.toggle('active');
        btn2.classList.toggle('activefail');
        btn2.classList.toggle('active');
        btn3.classList.toggle('activefail');
        btn3.classList.toggle('active');
        setTimeout(activabotones, 3000);
      }
    }
  }
}
//tercer boton
btn3.onclick = function() {
  if (btn3.classList.contains('active') || btn3.classList.contains('activefail')) {

  } else {
    contador = contador + 1;
    btn3.classList.toggle('active');
    i = array.indexOf(0);
    array = array.fill(1, i, i + 1);
    if (contador == 3) {
      if (JSON.stringify(array) == JSON.stringify(respuesta)) {
        console.log("si");
      } else {
        console.log("no");
        btn.classList.toggle('activefail');
        btn.classList.toggle('active');
        btn2.classList.toggle('activefail');
        btn2.classList.toggle('active');
        btn3.classList.toggle('activefail');
        btn3.classList.toggle('active');
        setTimeout(activabotones, 3000);
      }
    }
  }
}
function activabotones(){
        btn.classList.remove('activefail');
        btn.classList.remove('active');
        btn2.classList.remove('activefail');
        btn2.classList.remove('active');
        btn3.classList.remove('activefail');
        btn3.classList.remove('active');
        contador = 0;
        array = [0, 0, 0];
}
```

```css
/* Centrar elemento dentro de main */

.main {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1404px/*550px*/
  ;
  height: 658px/*315px*/
  ;
  line-height: 50px;
  /* Con «line-height» con el mismo valor numérico de la altura centras horizontalmente el texto */
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 7px;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/*Boton*/

.btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn.activefail {
  background: #f34121;
}

.btn.active {
  background: #2196f3;
}

.btn span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.btn:hover span {
  transform: scale(1.5) rotate(60deg) translateY(10px);
}

.btn.activefail span,
.btn.active span {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  border-left: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.btn span::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 12px -2px 0 #333, 12px -3px 0 #333 15px -1px 0 #333 6px -2px 0 #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn.activefail span::before,
.btn.activefail:hover span::before,
.btn.active:hover span::before,
.btn.active span::before {
  transform: scale(0);
}

.btn:hover span::before {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(50%) translateY(-10px);
}

.btn text {
  position: absolute;
  right: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn.activefail text,
.btn:hover text,
.btn.active text {
  transform: translateX(-50px) translateY(-5px) scale(0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Prueba</title>
</head>

<body>
  <container class="main">
    <a id="btn1" class="btn" style="position: absolute;/* width: 1vh; *//* flex-direction: row; */right: 5vw;/* left: auto; */ /* height: 100vh; *//* bottom: 0; */"><span></span><text>Delete</text></a>
    <a id="btn2" class="btn" style="position: absolute;/* width: 1vh; *//* flex-direction: row; */right: 33vw;/* left: auto; */ /* height: 100vh; *//* bottom: 0; */"><span></span><text>Delete</text></a>
    <a id="btn3" class="btn" style="position: absolute;/* width: 1vh; *//* flex-direction: row; */right: 61vw;/* left: auto; */ /* height: 100vh; *//* bottom: 0; */"><span></span><text>Delete</text></a>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```